# Eliminating commonly used words from a string in PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count, compare, words

I have code that takes a massive string from a SQL database and parses it into individual words and puts them into an array to be counted, with the goal of making a graph of the must used words, but I need to find a means of removing commonly used words.  I made a very basic array of words to compare to but it's not very effective.  Is their some means of a dictionary file i can compare it to? any ideas would be fantastic.

I am currently editing an existing "Data representation algorithm" at an internship and i really don't know where to start.  It has been suggested I use a dictionary file but not only do I not have have one, I wouldn't know how to compare it.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this, to provide more context?

Comment: are you looking for a dictionary file or a method of comparing words with a dictionary file?

Comment: You can set a list of common words, e.g. `a`, `the`, `as`, etc.. easily, but you'll still get tons of repeats based on whatever the topic of your text is. you'd still need to build out the list yourself.

Comment: This seems subjective. Please provide example of words you don't want included. How large of a dictionary are you looking for? Can you keep adding words to your dictionary by hand until you get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the in_array function:

```
<?php

$whitelist = array('a', 'the');

function whitelisted($var)
{
    global $whitelist;
    return (!in_array($var, $whitelist));
}

$str = "a lazy fox jumped over the lazy farmer";

print_r(array_count_values(array_filter(explode(" ", $str), "whitelisted")));
?>

//produces:

Array
(
    [lazy] => 2
    [fox] => 1
    [jumped] => 1
    [over] => 1
    [farmer] => 1
)
```

Of course, you could and should re-arrange this to work with your own scope (global is probably not ideal), but it should get you started on pruning out common words you don't  care to count.

http://ideone.com/kfNzM

Comment: Actually, I made a semantic mistake, as 'whitelist' should actually be called 'blacklist', as you're identifying words you wish to omit from your counts.